# how can I code the rest of this program so that the user guesses are marked if true?

Tags: java, loops, random, sequence

I am making this program that generates a random 4 character sequence of these characters CMFBOL. I need this program to accept a users input, check if their guesses are in the right position as the randomly generated sequence among the letters CMFBOL and return a 1 for a character in the right position and 0 in the in the wrong position. Here is what I have so far. To further elaborate on what my program will do, the random generator generates a sequence lets say for example CFBM, it stores that sequence of characters in a string and prompts the user to guess the sequence of these characters. If their guess letter is in the right position, it will print a 1. If their guess contains a correct character but in the wrong position, it will 0. For example, the random generator generates CMFB, and prompts the user to guess. The user types CLBO, and the program spits out 10. The 1 for C being in the right position and the 0 for the user guessing B but not in the right position.

```
else if (anotherScanner.hasNext("c|C"))
                    { 

                        c = anotherScanner.next();
                        //usersSelection = true;
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("COLOR CHALLENGE");
                        System.out.println("Valid color letters are:");
                        System.out.println("CMFBOL for Cyan Magenta Fushia BabyBlue Orange Lemon");

                        System.out.println("1) Guess:");
                        Random randomss = new Random();
                        String acronColor = "CMFBOL";
                        final int length = 4;

                        char let1 = acronColor.charAt(randomss.nextInt(length));
                        char let2 = acronColor.charAt(randomss.nextInt(length));
                        char let3 = acronColor.charAt(randomss.nextInt(length));
                        char let4 = acronColor.charAt(randomss.nextInt(length));

                        String acronColorRand = (""+let1+let2+let3+let4);
                        }
```

Comment: Didn't get your question?

Comment: OK, so, what does this program do, and how does it not match your expectations?

Comment: Still dont understand your question? What do u mean- all guesses will be marked if true?

Answer (score 0):

You look like a newbie so here is some logic on how you code should look like.
Try and understand what it does and improve it as you like.

```
    public static void main(String ... args){
    ........
    //some code here hopefully you alreday have 
    if (anotherScanner.hasNext("c|C"))
    { 

        c = anotherScanner.next();
        //usersSelection = true;
        String acronColor = "CMFBOL";
        System.out.println("COLOR CHALLENGE\n " +
                "Valid color letters are:\n" + acronColor +
                " for Cyan Magenta Fushia BabyBlue Orange Lemon");
        System.out.println("1) Guess:");
        Random randomss = new Random();
        final int length = 4;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            s.append(acronColor.charAt(randomss.nextInt(length)));
        }
        String acronColorRand = s.toString().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(eval(guess, acronColorRand));
        }
}


private String eval(String guess, String random){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    guess = guess.toUpperCase();
    for(int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++){
        char r = (guess.charAt(i) == random.charAt(i)) ? '1' : '0';
        s.append(r);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```